# jquery plugin for line hightlight

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, line, imagemap

I'm looking for a jquery plugin or similar that let you highlight a line or curves in the same way the imagemaps let you hightlight an area.

I've been looking for it for such a week and I haven't find anything.

Thanks.

Comment: herea are 10 highlight with example: https://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-text-highlighter-plugins/

Comment: @DanielH thanks Daniel but those are text highlighter. I'm looking for a imagemap with a line highlight option